# Use of single quote and double 'single quote' in PL/SQL block

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is a block of code which needs to be executed:

```
DECLARE
STR CLOB;
BEGIN

STR := ' CREATE TABLE TNAME AS

SELECT ... FROM INPUT_TABLE IP
WHERE ((IP.DATE_FIELD = TO_DATE('12.08.2013', 'DD.MM.sYYYY'))) ' ;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (STR);

END;
```

This block is formed in java code. On execution, this throws exception *org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException*. But when i change `TO_DATE('12.08.2013', 'DD.MM.sYYYY')` to `TO_DATE(''12.08.2013'', ''DD.MM.sYYYY'')` it executes successfully.

Here are my questions:

1) Why does it throw exception when i am using single quote?

2) What is difference between single quote and double 'single quotes'?

3) If i always use double 'single quotes', will there be any consequences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Oracle documentation on [text literals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#autoId0):

> In the top branch of the syntax:
>
> - *c* is any member of the user's character set. A single quotation mark (') within the literal must be preceded by an escape character.
>     To represent one single quotation mark within a literal, enter two
>     single quotation marks.

In your original version, the single quote immediately before the `12.08.2013` is treated as the end of that string - how would it know to treat it any other way? The `12.08` then becomes a number, but it's not in a useful place, so the parser doesn't know what to do with it, so you get an error.

In the second version you've escaped the quotes that are part of the actual text value, so Oracle knows they are part of the text, not marking the end of it. When it reaches the lone single quote before the semi-colon it sees *that* as the end of the string, which is what you want.

As @Parado says, try displaying the escape-quoted version and you'll see that it appears in a form that you could run directly, with the escaped single quotes appearing as strings in their own right as part of your  `create` statement.

You do need to escape all the single quotes, but you might find the alternative quoting syntax easier, as described in the second branch in the documentation. In your case that would be:

```
STR := q'[ CREATE TABLE TNAME AS
SELECT ... FROM INPUT_TABLE IP
WHERE ((IP.DATE_FIELD = TO_DATE('12.08.2013', 'DD.MM.sYYYY'))) ]';
```

This makes the quoted text literal easier to read and you don't have to worry about catching and escaping all the single quotes within it. You just need to make sure you pick a quote delimiter that doesn't appear in the text. Displaying that will look exactly the same as your escape-quoted version.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to ask your question directly. The best way to understand your problem is test it yourself. Instead of

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (STR);
```

please type the code

```
dbms_output.put_line(STR);
```

After that run your procedure with one quote and double quote. It will return sql commands. Try to run returned commands than I hope you will see and idea how it works.

**NOTE**: Don't forget to set `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`

Comment: Just looking at how stackoverflow coloured his code/query should give a pretty good hint at why the single quotes don't work :) Useful link: [Escape Character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_escaping)

Comment: The assignment of `STR` will fail before you get to the `dbms_output` though, when it reaches the `12`.