# ORA-20001: An error was encountered - -917 -ERROR- ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: sql, oracle

Am getting error ORA-00917: missing comma while running below procedure having insert statement, Appreciate help.

```
DECLARE err VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
 Sample_Proc ('INSERT',60682,'Tab_AUDIT',' ','insert into Tab_1 (Audit_Sk,Process_Sk,Process_Name,Process_Type,Audit_Categ_Cd,Src_Query_Txt ,Dest_Query_Txt ,Alert_Log_Message,INSERT_DATE,UPDATE_DATE, SUCCESS_EMAIL_FLAG, SUCESS_MAIL_TXT,ERROR_MAIL_TXT,WARN_MAIL_TXT,AUDIT_TYPE) values (60682,100160306,''prcs_name'',''AUDIT'',''AGGREGATE COMPARE''
,''SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tabb1 WHERE to_date(Create_Ts)= :b1 and etl_action_cd<>''D'';''
,''SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Tabb2 WHERE to_date(Create_Ts)= :b1 ;''
,''Comparison of data  - alert''
, 27-MAY-15 02:12:09
, 27-MAY-15 02:12:09
,''Y''
,''Validation ran successfully'' 
,''Validation  failed'' 
,''Validation  failed'' 
,''DND''))',' ',123,err);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ERR);
end;
```

Error report:

> ORA-20001: An error was encountered - -917 -ERROR- ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a comma... why would you want to pass a sql string into a proc to insert data?  But to your question, does the sql string work on a stand alone?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell, but I think it's probably these two terms:

```
, 27-MAY-15 02:12:09
, 27-MAY-15 02:12:09
```

which in a values clause will be seen as two seperate expressions with no comma between them - hence the error message.

You presumably meant those to be dates, not two expressions, and rather than just passing a string by just adding escaped quotes, you should explicitly convert with a format model:

```
, to_date(''27-MAY-15 02:12:09'', ''DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'')
, to_date(''27-MAY-15 02:12:09'', ''DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'')
```

This is still relying on the session NLS date language being English, but that's another issue...

As an aside, you might want to look into [the alternative quote syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#i42617), which would mean you didn't need to escape all the single quotes in your parameters. I won't attempt to convert your code, but there's a brief example with a date conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18098439/266304).

As a further aside, the ORA-20001 suggests your procedure has a `WHEN OTHERS` exception catch, which will probably be hiding details of where the actual exception occurred. Many consider that pattern to be a bug.